# Type mismatch when upgrading to ReactiveMongo 0.12.RC3

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I am currently upgrading to 0.12.RC3 in hope of fixing the [following issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355000/strange-mongoerror-with-reactivemongo-when-play-reloads-application) I am experiencing. After upgrading, I received a deprecation warning for the `collect` method.

So I moved from:

```
def find(query: JsObject = Json.obj())(implicit reader: Reads[T]): Future[List[T]] = {
    collection.flatMap(_.find(query).cursor[T](ReadPreference.nearest).collect[List]())
}
```

To:

```
def find(query: JsObject = Json.obj())(implicit reader: Reads[T]): Future[List[T]] = {
    collection.flatMap(_.find(query).cursor[T](ReadPreference.nearest).collect[List](Int.MaxValue, Cursor.FailOnError()))
}
```

However, unfortunately I get the following error:

> Type mismatch, expected: (JSONCollection) => Future[NotInferedS],
>   actual: (JSONCollection) => Any

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing some compiler message, and should see something like:

```
  (maxDocs: Int,stopOnError: Boolean)(implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[List[_],T,List[T]], implicit ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)scala.concurrent.Future[List[T]] <and>
  (maxDocs: Int,err: reactivemongo.api.Cursor.ErrorHandler[List[T]])(implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[List[_],T,List[T]], implicit ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)scala.concurrent.Future[List[T]]
 cannot be applied to (Int, reactivemongo.api.Cursor.ErrorHandler[Any])
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
           collection.flatMap(_.find(query).cursor[T](ReadPreference.nearest).collect[List](Int.MaxValue, Cursor.FailOnError()))
```

It means that in such case if you want to use the new `collect` instead of the deprecated one, you need to properly annotate the `ErrorHandler` (there `FailOnError`) with the result type: `FailOnError[List[T]]`

```
def find(query: JsObject = Json.obj())(implicit reader: Reads[T]): Future[List[T]] = collection.flatMap(_.find(query).cursor[T](ReadPreference.nearest).collect[List](Int.MaxValue, Cursor.FailOnError[List[T]]()))
```